# how to send variables and upload a video in the same Try catch in doInBackground? [Android]

Tags: android

I am trying to send variables to my PHP script on my server before i upload my video. I use this code in other try catch blocks in my DoInBackground method to send my variables to a different PHP script:

```
URL url = new URL(UploadVideo_URL);//Create a new URL and put there variable "register_URL" into it.
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Create a httpConnection and open it
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");//Use the request method
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("ProductAccountName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductAccountName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("fileName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("ProductName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductName, "UTF-8");





                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
```

i thought i could do the same with this try catch block (which uploads the video) but when i try to use it in this code an error occurs.

```
try{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(UploadVideo_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);









                OutputStream OS = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("ProductAccountName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductAccountName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("fileName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("ProductName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductName, "UTF-8");





                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();









                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();


                return "video uploaded";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My question is:

> how can i send a variable and then upload my video in the same Try catch block?

Heres the error:

```
03-15 12:33:50.044 21790-21790/com.wilsapp.wilsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.wilsapp.wilsapp, PID: 21790
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:660)
                                                                 at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:27)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I think the reason why its erroring out is because i have the code in the wrong place.

its important that i send the variables then upload the video in the same try catch block! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste complete doInBackground() code as the crash logs depict the line which you have not pasted.